# java error in org.apache(netbeans)

Tags: apache, import

I have a code written in java. when i load it in NetBeans it shows an error in the java code import line: " The import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration dosent exist"
How can i fix this error..??

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add proper library in project properties.

Or maven dependency if you are using maven.